# Show that for all $n\geq1$, $ \int_0^1f(x^n)\,dx\geq f(\frac{1}{n+1})$.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ has second order derivative on $[0,\,1]$ and $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in[0,\,1]$. Show that for all $n\geq1$, 
>   $$
> \int_0^1f(x^n)\,dx\geq f(\frac{1}{n+1}).
> $$

When $n=1$, since $f$ is a convex function, we have
$$
f(x)\geq f(t)+f'(t)(x-t)
$$
for every fixed $t\in[0,\,1]$.

By integrate corresponding to $x$, we have $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\geq f(\frac{1}{2})$.

For $n\geq2$, I set $F(x)=f(x^n)$, which is also has $F''(x)>0$ on $[0,\,1]$. Similarly, we have
$$
\int_0^1 f(x^n)\,dx\geq f(t^n)+f'(t^n)\frac{n}{2}t^{n-1}-f'(t^n)t.
$$

By letting $t=\frac{n}{2}t^{n-1}$, however, I could not get that $t^n=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Integrate
$$
f(x^n)\ge f\left(\frac 1{n+1}\right) + f'\left(\frac 1{n+1}\right)\left(x^n-\frac 1{n+1}\right).
$$

Comment: +1. Very neat argument!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hmm, I thought that was obvious. Well, sometimes brains work differently. That's why we should work in teams.